# How to use ordinal function to turn input box values into ordinal number and display it

Tags: javascript, function, ordinal

I am trying to take input from one input box, turn it into ordinal form using getGetOrdinal() function and then display it in second box using getO() function.I am wondering whether I have to turn input box value into an integer before it is used by getGetOrdinal() function.

```js
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
   var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
       v=n%100;
   return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
 
 
function getO() {
 var inOne = document.getElementById("one").value;//*takes value
 var result = getGetOrdinal("inOne");//* passes inOne into getGetOrdinal
 var inTwo = document.getElementById("two");
 inTwo.textContent = result;//*displays ordinal number in second box
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  
<form>
<input id="one" type="number"><!-- first input box-->
<button type="button" onlick="getO()">submit</button><!-- should turn value of firsdt input box into ordinal number-->
<input type="number" id="two"><!-- should display ordinal number-->


</form>
```

Comment: Yes you have to convert it to an integer...

Comment: you should change the `getGetOrdinal("inOne")` to `getGetOrdinal(inOne)`. you are not passing the variable but a string containing `inOne`.

Answer (score 1):

1) you should change the `getGetOrdinal("inOne")` to `getGetOrdinal(inOne)`. you are not passing the variable but a string containing `inOne`.

2) also what you've got to change is to set the `value` property of the second input not the `textContent`

3) And for the last thing, let's make sure the `argument` for the `getGetOrdinal` function is a number

```
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
  n = +n; // This is for numbers like '5e2'
  if(isNaN(n)) { // <-- 3
   throw new Error('You should provide a number as the argument for getGetOrdinal function')
  }
  var s = ["th","st","nd","rd"],
      v = n%100;
  return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}


function getO() {
  var inOne = document.getElementById("one").value;
  var result = getGetOrdinal(inOne); // <-- 1
  var inTwo = document.getElementById("two");
  inTwo.value = result; // <-- 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had quite a few errors. Here's a correct way of doing it:

```js
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
  var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
    v = n % 100;
  return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}

function getO() {
  var inOne = document.getElementById("one").value; // takes value
  var result = getGetOrdinal(parseInt(inOne)); // passes inOne into getGetOrdinal
  var inTwo = document.getElementById("two");
  inTwo.value = result; // displays ordinal number in second box
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- first input box-->
  <input id="one" type="number">
  <!-- should turn value of first input box into ordinal number-->
  <button type="button" onclick="getO()">submit</button>
  <!-- should display ordinal number-->
  <input type="text" id="two">
</form>
```

If you would like to know a method of doing this with better practices, here's another solution (which has the benefit of updating immediately):

```js
var inOne = document.getElementById("one"); // input
var inTwo = document.getElementById("two"); // output

function getGetOrdinal(n) {
  var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
    v = n % 100;
  return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}

function getO() {
  // convert to number
  var number = +inOne.value;
  
  // error checking
  if (isNaN(number) || parseInt(number) !== number || number <= 0) {
    inTwo.value = "invalid positive integer";
  } else {
    var result = getGetOrdinal(number); // passes inOne into getGetOrdinal
    inTwo.value = result; // displays ordinal number in second box
  }
}

inOne.addEventListener('input', getO);
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- first input box-->
  <input id="one" type="number" placeholder="Choose a number">
  <!-- should display ordinal number-->
  <input id="two" type="text" placeholder="Ordinal number" readonly="readonly">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

you did mistake in writing code, correct it,
instead of `onlick`, change it to `onclick`

```
<button type="button" onclick="getO()">submit</button>
```

one more mistake is here, he is getting the input value into `inOne` but he is passing as `string not variable`

```
 var inOne = document.getElementById("one").value;//*takes value
 var result = getGetOrdinal("inOne");//* passes inOne into getGetOrdinal
```

`textContent` can be used only for text elements only not for form elements. need to use `value`

```
inTwo.value = result;
```

And also, **you need to change the input type to text than number**

Comment: Maybe he wanted the button to trigger when it was `lick`ed... but in all seriousness this isn't a full answer.

Comment: he is doing mistake in another place also, he is taking input value and sending as string not as variable

Comment: Yes [this was already pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38643491/1541563) long before you wrote this...