# Can I display ordinal text in a input number form tag?

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to display text instead of numbers in a `<input type="numnber">` tag, and *not* in some other form field?

```html
<input type="number" id="numbers" min="1" max="10" value="1">
```

I want to display ordinal numerals instead of numbers, i.e. 1st instead of 1, 2nd instead of 2, etc...

Comment: No, <input> elements of type number are used to let the user enter a number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ordinal function to turn input box values into ordinal number and display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643367/how-to-use-ordinal-function-to-turn-input-box-values-into-ordinal-number-and-dis)

Comment: @Vikas No, I'm looking a way to display them in the same element. According to your first answer, it appears that it's not possible.

Comment: no its not possibe to put anything other then number

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem with other way, I just give this sample so you can move on.

```html
<input type="number" id="numbers" min="1" max="10" value="1">
    <button 
        onclick="
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = 
            document.getElementById('numbers').value == 1 
            ? document.getElementById('numbers').value+'st'
            : document.getElementById('numbers').value == 2
            ? document.getElementById('numbers').value+'nd'
            : document.getElementById('numbers').value == 3
            ? document.getElementById('numbers').value+'rd'
            : document.getElementById('numbers').value+'th'
            ">
        Show
    </button>
<p id="result"></p>
```